# Selecting Entity Using Linq query with join and including nested property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm battling to retrieve a single Model/Entity using EntityFramework and Linq.

I have a Business with Members, I'm trying to retrieve the users' business based on the BusinessMembers table/entity.

I have the following entities/models:

```
public partial class Business
{
    public Business()
    {
        BusinessMembers = new HashSet<BusinessMember>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ID_BusinessStatus { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public virtual BusinessStatus BusinessStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BusinessMember> BusinessMembers { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
 public partial class BusinessStatus
{
    public BusinessStatus()
    {
        Businesses = new HashSet<Business>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
}
```

I then have the following method to return a Single Business Instance:

```
        public Business GetBusinessForUser(string userId)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext(_connectionString))
        {
            var q =
                   from b in db.Businesses
                   join bm in db.BusinessMembers on b.ID equals bm.ID_Business
                   where bm.UserId == userId
                   select b;

            return q.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Problem I'm having is I want to 'Include' the BusinessStatus for that single Business entity and don't know how to do this.

I need to be able to do:

```
Business businessEntity = _dataServices.GetBusinessForUser(userId);

        if (businessEntity.BusinessStatus.Code == "ACT")
        {
            // Whatever
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add this to the list of usings

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Then you can use the .Include() method to load additional children in your query

```
public Business GetBusinessForUser(string userId)
{
    using (var db = new MyContext(_connectionString))
    {
        var q =
               (from b in db.Businesses
               join bm in db.BusinessMembers on b.ID equals bm.ID_Business
               where bm.UserId == userId
               select b).Include(business => business.BusinessStatus);

        return q.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

I would also avoid using the `join` method explicitly. If your model has correct relationships (e.g. foreign keys), you should be able to just do this:

```
var q = db.Businesses
          .Where(b => b.BusinessMembers.Any(bm => bm.UserId == userId))
          .Include(b => b.BusinessStatus);

return q.FirstOrDefault();
```

or even

```
var q = db.BusinessMembers
          .Where(bm => bm.UserId == userId)
          .Select(bm => bm.Business)
          .Include(b => b.BusinessStatus);
```

Comment: Thanks gaiazov, what does the .Any method do?

Comment: It returns true if any items in the collection match a condition. For example -
  var items = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  
  Console.WriteLine(items.AsQueryable().Any(x => x < 2)); // true
  Console.WriteLine(items.AsQueryable().Any(x => x > 5)); // false